# What does a lambda prompt indicate at the command line?

Tags: windows, shell, lambda, prompt, cmder

I just installed `Cmder` on a Windows box as a precursor to getting Cygwin installed and a bash shell going.

It's my first time installing it, and I notice the prompt character used is lambda 'λ'. I'm more used to seeing '$' as a default prompt character, at least in a *nix environment.

Does a lambda indicate anything in particular from some other computing tradition? Or is this the default just because it looks cool?

Comment: StackOverflow's scope is limited to questions that are both ["unique to software development"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and practical in nature. This is probably a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it serves a particular use other than looking cool.